# Mystic error of double inclusion of library in c++

Tags: c++, include

Sorry for the lame title, but i really have no idea about what's happening. It seems to be declaring a function, and a variable twice. Maybe im including it twice somewhere, but the project is really small, and i cant find where it is included.

My code is in this [github repo](https://github.com/throoze/gameTrees). when i do `make`, this is the output:

```
g++  arbolesJuego.cpp main.cc  -o othello
/tmp/ccwVFD8e.o: In function `lookup()':
main.cc:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `lookup()'
/tmp/cc3YvuYq.o:arbolesJuego.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/tmp/ccwVFD8e.o:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `trans'
/tmp/cc3YvuYq.o:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

why is this happening? any help will be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Since, the provided link is to a repo, and it will be improved (i hope hehehe), i paste the wrong code next:

```
stored_info_t lookup() {
  stored_info_t info;
  return info;
};

hash_table_t trans;
```

`trans`  is being used in the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make this function `inline` on line 35 of `hashTable.h`

```
stored_info_t lookup() {
  return NULL;
}
```

it should get rid of the error.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one of your problems:

The definition

> ```
> hash_table_t trans;
> ```

appears in a header file.  Since headers are duplicated into each compilation unit using them, you end up with multiple variables with the same name.  That causes the linker error.

The fix is to say

```
extern hash_table_t trans;
```

in the header, and

```
hash_table_t trans;
```

in exactly one source file.

A similar approach will work for your other errors.

Comment: Thanks! do i have to redeclare them in the `.cpp` files?

Comment: also, this works with the variable trans, but didn't work with the function (`lookup()`)... is there some similar reserved word in c++ to use in these cases?

Comment: @Throoze: The same approach applies: You must move the definition to a source file, and leave only a declaration in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can wrap it around namespace to create a static context like so

```
namespace{
    hash_table_t trans;
    stored_info_t lookup() {
      return NULL;
    }
}
```

Note, you should avoid globals if possible.